# Difference between class and beanName attributes of jsp:useBean

Tags: jsp

What is the difference between `class` attribute and `beanName` attribute of `jsp:useBean` tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just read [the `<jsp:useBean>` documentation (page 35)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/syntaxref12-149806.pdf). Here's an extract of relevance:

> - `class="package.class" type="package.class"`
>
>   Instantiates a bean from the class named in `class` and assigns the bean the data type you specify in `type`. The value of `type` can be the same as `class`, a superclass of `class`, or an interface implemented by `class`.
>
>   The class you specify in `class` must not be abstract and must have a public, no-argument constructor. The package and class names you use with both `class` and `type` are case sensitive.
> - `beanName="{package.class | <%= expression %>}" type="package.class"`
>
>   Instantiates a bean from a class, a serialized template, or an expression that evaluates to a class or serialized template. When you use `beanName`, the bean is instantiated by the `java.beans.Beans.instantiate` method. The `Beans.instantiate` method checks whether the package and class you specify represents a class or a serialized template. If they represent a serialized template, `Beans.instantiate` reads the serialized form (which has a name like `package.class.ser`) using a class loader.
>
>   The value of `type` can be the same as `beanName`, a superclass of `beanName`, or an interface implemented by `beanName`. The package and class names you use with both `beanName` and `type` are case sensitive.

Comment: @Andres: JSP has been deprecated. Fortunately I already extracted the relevant part into the answer.

Comment: @BalusC - how do you mean JSP has been deprecated? I think what is meant is just the link should be to Oracle and not Sun which is now 'deprecated'.

Comment: @user3763130: JSP was end of 2009 succeeded by Facelets and Oracle apparently didn't bother to maintain old JSP documentation for a lifetime. If you can find the right Oracle link containing exactly the extracted part in my answer, be my guest to fix the broken link in my answer.

Comment: FYI example ... You want to use a bean that is stored in `com/enthu/GUI.ser` file. Which of following statements correctly defines the tag that accesses the bean?  the answer is `<jsp:useBean id="pref" beanName="com.enthu.GUI" type="com.enthu.GUI"/>`  .ser file is nothing but a regular file in which any Java object is stored in a serialized format. This is usually done using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj); and by convention the extension of such a file is .ser.

Comment: Cont..First the container looks for a .ser file under the directory as specified in the beanName attribute. If the file is available, it is used to instantiate the bean using `java.bean.Beans.intantiate(...)` method. Otherwise, the beanName is assumed to be a class name and if that class has a public no args constructor, an object of that class is instantiated. Otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: check : http://www-it.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/courses/WDB/references/JSP%20syntax/syntaxref08.html