# Getting InstantiationException while using <jsp:useBean>

Tags: jsp, instantiationexception, usebean

Can anybody tell me what is the exact meaning of type and class attributes of  `jsp:usebean` tag.?
I am getting an exception **InstantiationException** while using them in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extract from docs,

> The jsp:useBean element declares that the page will use a bean that is
>   stored within and is accessible from the specified scope, which can be
>   application, session, request, or page. If no such bean exists, the
>   statement creates the bean and stores it as an attribute of the scope
>   object .

The value of the **id** attribute

> determines the name of the bean in the scope and the identifier used
>   to reference the bean in EL expressions, other JSP elements, and
>   scripting expressions .

The value supplied for the **class** attribute

> must be a fully qualified class
>   name. Note that beans cannot be in the unnamed package. Thus the
>   format of the value must be package-name.class-name.

Instantiation Exception is thrown on many scenarios, basically when you dont specify the required values for the attributes of the `useBean` tag.

**See also**

- [A startup tutorial on `<jsp:useBean>`
  tag](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action)
- [Difference between class and beanName attributes of jsp:useBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710733/difference-between-class-and-beanname-attributes-of-jspusebean)
- [java.lang.InstantiationException: bean [name] not found within scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842892/java-lang-instantiationexception-bean-name-not-found-within-scope)
- [javax.servlet.ServletException: bean [name] not found within scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270444/javax-servlet-servletexception-bean-name-not-found-within-scope)